# return или break для выхода из цикла?

Tags: java

Допустим у нас есть код вида:

```
while (true){
    ...
    if (...){
    return; // or break?
    }
}
```

Как правильно выйти из цикла, return или break?

Answer (score 6):

Все зависит от того, что вам надо. Если вам надо выйти полностью из метода, то тогда `return`, а если только из цикла - то `break`.

Примеры.

Тут стоит использовать `return`, т.к. после цикла нет ничего + надо вернуть какое-либо значение

```
while(true) {
    ....
    if (...) {
        return "someReturnValue"
    }
}
```

А тут стоит использовать `break`, т.к. после цикла идет какая-то логика - в цикле мы ждем, пока наш объект не прогрузиться, и после этого уже получаем объект и работаем с ним

```
while(true)
    if (myObjectIsLoad()) {
        break;
    }
}
var myObject = getMyObject(); 
....
```

Answer (score -3):

Синтаксически оба подхода выход через `return/break` равнозначны.

Однако, с точки зрения читабельности кода, все таки предпочтителен `break`, поскольку  выход из функции во многих местах затрудняет понимание логики функции.